# Spreadsheet layout validation

Tags: exception

I created a feature to check if a spreadsheet has the correct layout, before uploading it to the database, it works perfectly for spreadsheets that are outside the requested standard. The problem is, when I upload it to check one that has the correct layout, it gives the same exception message as if it were wrong.

This was the function I created to do the validation:

```
private function validateFields(string $file): self
    {
        $fh = fopen($file, 'r');
        $header = fgetcsv($fh);
        fclose($fh);

        foreach ($header as $value) {
            if (!in_array(strtoupper($value),
             self::MAP) || count(self::MAP) != count($header)) {
                 throw new \Exception('Invalid archive layout.');
             }
        }
        return $this;
    }
```

And here is where i'm calling this function with a try catch for this exception message:

```
public function execute()
    {
        $files = $this->getRequest()->getFiles('files');

        $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
        $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*');

        if (empty($files['tmp_name'])) {
            $this->messageManager->addWarningMessage(__('No files were uploaded.'));
            return $resultRedirect;
        }

        try {
            $file = $this->setExtensionInTemporaryFile($files['tmp_name'], $files['name']);

            $fileData = $this->file->readFile($file, self::SPREADSHEET_TAB);

            $this->validateFields('$file');
            
            $this->saveCustomerRelatedAttribute->execute($fileData);

            $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage(__('Customer segment attributes save successfuly.'));
        } catch (\InvalidArgumentException $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage(__('Make sure the file extension refers to a csv.'));
        } catch (CouldNotSaveException $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage(
                __('One or more lines do not contain correct values. Check and try again.')
            );
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage(__('The csv layout is invalid. Check and try again.')
            );
        }
        return $resultRedirect;
    }
```

Comment: Why is this like this $this->validateFields('$file'); why not like this $this->validateFields($file);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this, maybe it helps:

> Important! We recommend that you use a program that supports UTF-8
> encoding, such as Notepad++ or OpenOffice Calc, to edit CSV files.
> Microsoft Excel inserts additional characters into the column header
> of the CSV file, which can prevent the data from being imported back
> into Magento. If you work on the Mac, you can save your data in the
> CSV (Windows) format.

Reference: https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/system/data-csv.html